vscode extension - promise handling
I am on the way to write my first vscode extension in js.
I currently face a problem, that I do not understand. Most likely because of too little knowledge about js.
So this is my code in extension.js
const mypromise = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
  .edit((editBuilder) => {
    editBuilder.insert(mysecondpos, "\nhello world\n");
  })
  .then(
    function () {
      console.log("success");
    },
    function () {
      console.log("fail");
    }
  );

This shall insert the line "hello world" at mysecondpos, which is of type vscode.Position.
And it works. The line appears, when I execute the extension using Extension Development Host.
But when I close the Extension Development Host window, I get the follwing errors (see image):

Exception has occured: Canceled: Canceled
Paused on promise rejection

What I tried and what I expected
I added the two callback functions to .then in the above code in order to react to a rejected promise. Although I do not understand, why the promise gets the state rejected. because the change succeeded.
It seems to me that the whole operation is not done, when I close the Extension Development Host window. That it still waits for something or so. But I expected that I can simply close the window without any error.
